# How to efficiently count words in a json file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a json file such as

```
[{'start': '11.240', 'end': '11.840', 'word': 'sure', 'v': 1},
 {'start': '12.740', 'end': '13.130', 'word': 'look', 'v': 1},
 {'start': '14.140', 'end': '14.480', 'word': 'no no', 'v': 1},
 {'start': '14.480', 'end': '14.620', 'word': "we're", 'p': ',', 'v': 1},
 {'start': '14.620', 'end': '14.790', 'word': 'not', 'v': 1},
 {'start': '14.790', 'end': '15.050', 'word': 'going', 'v': 1}]
```

I could just loop through it like

```
i = 0
for obj in objects:
    i = i + len(obj["word"].split())
```

but for a large directory with a large number of files, this seems to be bit slow. How can I count this in a efficient manner?

Comment: this is about as efficient as it will get. Almost *certainly* your bottleneck is not this, rather, it's probably the file I/O

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sum()` function instead of writing your own loop. And instead of splitting the string, which has to allocate a new list, just count the number of spaces (assuming each word is separated by just one space).

```
word_count = sum(obj["word"].count(" ")+1 for obj in objects)
```

Comment: This still requires a python-level for-loop. Some fo the arithmetic stuff might be optimized, but I don't think this will be significantly faster

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Any method will be O(n), you need a loop somewhere.

Comment: So the best we can do is improve the efficiency of the body of the loop.

Comment: Other than the caveat I mention in the answer, why wouldn't it be correct?

Comment: Right, using `.count` may be an actual optimization, my point is, `sum(<gen exp>)` will almost certainly be *slightly slower* than the equivalent for-loop

Answer (score 0):

**use sum():**

```
count = sum(len(obj["word"].split()) for obj in objects)
```

**The second method is mine:**

> [image: code]

**Output:**

> [image: output]

Comment: this still requires a python-level loop

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes it's still requires for-loop, but it's so more faster. i tested

Comment: How much faster?

Comment: @hmnFalahi I doubt it. Provide your profiling code.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode It definitely isn't faster. They may be profiling a loop outside a function, which will be slow due to the global lookups. Wrapping the loop in a function, e.g `def naive_loop_sum(data): ...` and I'm seeing better performance. Which is to be *expected*.

Comment: This is not a fair profiling. (also, **provide this as text, not screenshots**).

Comment: answer updated @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @hmnFalahi yeah, your profiling is not good, you have to wrap the for-loop in a function. Doing this in the global scope will slow *everything down*. Try it. EDIT: also, use something like `timeit`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I didn't mean I believed it, I just wanted to see their results/code :-). For *larger* lists the generator btw does seem [slightly faster](https://pastebin.com/raw/FX00RSn5) more often than not.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga And [after localizing `len`](https://pastebin.com/raw/tYDZ8KCW).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode sure, but you don't even have to go that far (and in general, I wouldn't do that sort of thing)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What do you mean with go that far and that sort of thing?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If you mean the `len` localization, that was because otherwise my "mappy" solution has somewhat of an unfair advantage, as the loop/gen solutions weren't as optimized regarding local/global access as they could've been.

Answer (score 0):

**sum()**

```
count = sum(len(obj["word"].split()))
for obj in objects
```

Comment: This is _exactly_ the same as the answer provided an hour before yours. (Okay, the parenthesis are a bit different, but it’s functionally equivalent.) Please review existing answers before posting—and upvote answers that you find useful, instead of reiterating their advice as new answers.